# mysql case when date contains `

Tags: mysql, date, case

I'm trying to figure out how to do a case when the date contains a certain year.

I've got:

```
    use leeds_new; 

select 
    sc.salesforce_id,
    qq.survey_id,

    case when 
        (qq.survey_id = 1 and  qq.`name` in('Q5.1_2','Q5.1_3','Q5.1_4') and qrd.`value` in(5,6)) then 1 else 0 end as interest_2015,
    case when qrd.date_end like *%2015%* then '2015' else 0 end as responded_2015, ## THIS LINE
    case when 
        (qq.survey_id = 2 and qq.`name` in('Q5.1_2','Q5.1_3','Q5.1_4','Q5.1_5','Q11.3_1','Q11.3_2','Q11.3_3','Q11.3_4') and qrd.`value` in(2,3,6,7)) then 1 else 0 end as interest_2016,
    case when 
        (qq.survey_id = 3 and qq.`name` in('Q1.2_2','Q1.2_3','Q1.2_4','Q1.2_5','Q7.4_1','Q7.4_2','Q7.4_3','Q7.4_4') and qrd.`value` in(2,3)) then 1 else 0 end as interest_2017,
    case when 
        (qq.survey_id = 187 and qq.`name` in('Q2.2_2','Q2.2_3','Q2.2_4','Q2.2_5','Q9.4_1','Q9.4_2','Q9.4_3','Q9.4_4') and qrd.`value` in(2,3,6,7)) then 1 else 0 end as interest_2018

 from 

qualtrics_responses as qr
    inner join qualtrics_response_details as qrd on qr.id = qrd.response_id
    inner join qualtrics_questions as qq on qrd.question_id = qq.id
    inner join salesforce_contacts as sc on qr.member_id = sc.salesforce_id
    inner join salesforce_alumni_regions_federated as ar on sc.alumni_region_id = ar.alumni_region_id

    where (

        (qq.survey_id = 1 and  qq.`name` in('Q5.1_2','Q5.1_3','Q5.1_4') and qrd.`value` in(5,6))
    or (qq.survey_id = 2 and qq.`name` in('Q5.1_2','Q5.1_3','Q5.1_4','Q5.1_5','Q11.3_1','Q11.3_2','Q11.3_3','Q11.3_4') and qrd.`value` in(2,3,6,7))
    or (qq.survey_id = 3 and qq.`name` in('Q1.2_2','Q1.2_3','Q1.2_4','Q1.2_5','Q7.4_1','Q7.4_2','Q7.4_3','Q7.4_4') and qrd.`value` in(2,3))
    or (qq.survey_id = 187 and qq.`name` in('Q2.2_2','Q2.2_3','Q2.2_4','Q2.2_5','Q9.4_1','Q9.4_2','Q9.4_3','Q9.4_4') and qrd.`value` in(2,3,6,7))

    )
;
```

The date data is in this format: '2017-04-14 13:17:56'

I basically want to say if the date contains a certain year, then return the year.

Is there another way to do this? I've spent a bunch of time searching and I'm a little stuck.

Thanks!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Comment: I looked way too long for such a simple answer! :) ha. Thank you!